# Telegram API (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telethon.errors.rpc_errors_401')

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook, telegram, telethon

I tried to run the telegram API through my Jupyter Notebook but while importing it showed the following error

**from telethon import TelegramClient
----> 2 from telethon.errors.rpc_errors_401 import SessionPasswordNeededError
      3 
      4 # (1) Use your own values here
      5 api_id = 11111
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telethon.errors.rpc_errors_401'**

Comment: How did you install `telethon`, and what's your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

The module to be used for `SessionPasswordNeededError` is `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist`. Try using `from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import SessionPasswordNeededError`